# how to implement trained nlp spacy model in a front end application

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, spacy

I am new to ML and DS. I have done many projects on Kaggle or Colab but this is my first time doing an NLP project on Resume Parsing using spacy.

I have trained my model using data from 200 resumes and now i have a model best and a model last

i tried this model on the test data and it works almost flawlessly by returning the label from the text.

I want guidance on how i can use this model and create either a web app or a mobile app

I have some level of knowledge on how to make a material app using flutter and also java mobile apps

but i jus dont know how i can proceed from here

my project is just a python notebook on google colab and everytime i wanna use it i have to train the model for 2 hours

The model just returns labelled data like name, college name, degree, companies worked at and so on from the txt data that i extracted using PyMupdf

[github repo](https://github.com/simpostor/resumeparse)

Tbh i didnt try much because i just dont know how to approach this

Comment: Congrats !!
You could now build a web api where you load the model and use it to predict the labels of incoming resumes. Try FastAPI

Comment: oooh nice
i have worked with free APIs but i never tried building a web api